# Is being a bystander considered as being a sin?

Tags: karma, sin, dharma-shastras

If a fight is taking place or someone is being harassed/bullied, what do the Shastras say we do? If for instance, I do nothing to help the victim but just take no action, will this be wrong?

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15702/does-one-gain-p%C4%81pa-or-pu%E1%B9%87ya-by-remaining-neutral-in-a-moral-crisis